# Getting the day info only from a date int C/C++

Tags: c++, c, date, time

I have a program that is getting a date from some protocol, in format of `DD/MM/YYYY`.

The Problem is that I need to know the info of that day(day of the week, day in the year...) and I don't know how to do it.

Usually, when I want to get a day info, I am using **`time(time_t*)`** and convert the result to **`tm struct`** using **`localltime_r(tm*, time_t*)`** and then I have everything i need.

But in this case, this is not the current time(so I can not use **`time(time_t*)`**) and I don't have nothing except the date.

I can create a new **`tm struct`** and fill only **`tm_year`**, **`tm_mon`**, **`tm_mday`** and use **`mktime(tm*)`**, but I am not sure if this will give me the right detail's of the desired date.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? A `tm struct` is by no means bound to the *current* date.

Comment: "use mktime(tm*), but i am not sure if this will give me the right detail's of the desired date" - As long as you zero out the other fields yes it should work.

Comment: i was not sure if putting zeros in the unknown fields will give the right info. i will give it a try

Comment: gcc 7.2 (mingw) gives correct result...

Comment: Actually looking again you might need to be careful with the is_dst flag :-/ Here's [a mirror of GNU libc's mktime](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/glibc-2.23/time/mktime.c#L343) and you can see that it reads year, mon, mday plus hour min sec (but then =0 means midnight) and also the is_dst flag.

Comment: Read the [documentation for `mktime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime).  If you fill in the date you know (including month and day of month), and call `mktime`, `mktime` will compute the day of week and day of year for you.  You should set the time to 12:00:00, and `tm_isdst` to 0 or -1.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  It works with C++11 and later, ported to gcc, clang and VS.  It has been accepted into the C++20 draft specification.

Example code:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{"09/07/2018"};
    sys_days sd;
    in >> parse("%d/%m/%Y", sd);
    cout << "Day of the week is " << weekday{sd} << '\n';
    cout << "Day of the year is " << sd - sys_days{year_month_day{sd}.year()/1/0} << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Day of the week is Mon
Day of the year is 190d
```

If you would rather do the computations yourself, [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) are extremely efficient *non-iterative* public domain algorithms for calendrical computations.  The library referenced above is nothing but a type-safe wrapper around these algorithms with more pleasant syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to get write methods which get the day of week/year as opposed to using a library, here's what I would do.

You're going to need to take leap years into account. For any given year, determine whether or not it is a leap year. Something like this would work (using a formula found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm:

```
    bool isLeapYear(short year)
    {
        bool leapYear = false;
        if (((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
            leapYear = true;
        return leapYear;
    }
```

From this, calculating the day of the year is straightforward. Simply add up all the days for each month, if it is a leap year, add 29 days onto your tally for day of year if you come across February.

As for finding the day of the week, it really helps if you start with some *lower bound* for the year (in this case LOWYEAR = 1760) and start with the first day of that year (STARTDAYOFWEEK = 2). Each day of the week is corresponds to a number (0-6) where Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc.

```
int DayOfWeek(void)
{
   //jan 1 1760 was tuesday (2)
    short dayCount = STARTDAYOFWEEK;
    for (unsigned i = LOWYEAR; i < year; i++)
    {
        if (isLeapYear(i))
            dayCount += 2;
        else
            dayCount++;
    }
    return (dayCount + dayOfYear) - 1) % DAYSINWEEK;
}
```

Finding the day of week is now really easy, after calculating dayCount, the day of week is found by adding dayCount with dayOfYear and modding by DAYSINWEEK (6).

The resulting number will correspond to the day of week (0-6).

Comment: While this is fine for learning, if you're writing production code for an environment where Standard C library functions are available, *please* use the standard library functions, please *don't* roll your own.  Date- and time-manipulation code is notoriously difficult to get right.  Even if you do manage to get it right (and what you have looks okay), you don't want to saddle your successors with the worry of wondering whether you got it right, and of maintaining it if/when requirements change.

Comment: Right. I just figured he could learn something from my answer. :)